# How do I align text to fit in a Div that is moved down with Top: 50px;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a div that appears on the .hover of another div, and move the div that shows up on .hover move down below the div that is being hovered over. I've got this part working just fine but, the text is below the hovering div.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="interface.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<head>
<div id="elementID">
<div id="woodenPickaxe">
    <a class='craftWoodenPickaxe' href='#'>
        <span class='craftingButton'>Craft Wooden Pickaxe</span>
        <div id="woodenPickaxePopup"> Cost 50 wood </div>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Jscript

```
$(function(){
$("#woodenPickaxe").hover(function() { 
    $("#woodenPickaxePopup").toggle(); 
});
```

CSS

```
#elementID{
height: 500px;
width: 500px;
background: green;
padding-top: 100px;    
}
#woodenPickaxePopup{
height: 50px;
width: 158px;
background: white;
display: none;
position: relative;
top: 50px;
}

.craftingButton {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#616161;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    height:48px;
    line-height:50px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -ms-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;
    float: left;
}
.craftingButton:active {
    position:relative;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: solid; 
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    top:1px;
}

.craftingButton:hover {
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
}

padding-top: 100px;
}
.craftingButton {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#616161;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    height:48px;
    line-height:50px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -ms-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;
    float: left;
}
.craftingButton:active {
    position:relative;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: solid; 
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    top:1px;
}

.craftingButton:hover {
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
}
```

[JSfiddle Example:](http://jsfiddle.net/RBJ9R/1594/)

As you can see, the hovering works fine, the divs all work properly, except for the text in my woodenPickaxePopup div, it's below the div where it should be.

Edit: I apologize for the profanity used, I forgot about it when I made that jsfiddle last night and was getting upset that I couldn't solve this problem.

Comment: Hm @AaronD best not to use curse words for ids on this site - keep it classy!

Comment: I ran the code and I couldn't seem to see the #woodenPickaxePopUp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you're using javascript to show `woodenPickaxePopup` div? You can achieve the same thing without javascript.

Here's a working update:
http://jsfiddle.net/RBJ9R/1600/

The parts that changed:

```
#woodenPickaxePopup{
    height: 50px;
    width: 158px;
    background: white;
    display: none;
    position: absolute; // changed to absolute
    top: 50px;
}

// added this
.craftWoodenPickaxe {
    position: relative;
}

// added this
.craftWoodenPickaxe:hover #woodenPickaxePopup {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I could not seem to get this to work on my webpage, I see that it works in the jsfiddle but when I implement the code into my page it don't work like it does on the fiddle at all. Nothing is showing up on hover, I tried something similar to this method before I went with the javascript route but couldn't get desired results.

Comment: If you're using Chrome you could open the Developer Tools and inspect these elements and see if there's any other CSS overwriting the CSS above. Might have some to do with specificity.

Comment: The html above and the html on your website is different. The <a> should be wrapping woodenPickaxePopup too. Like this: <div id="woodenPickaxe">
    <a class="craftWoodenPickaxe" href="#">
        <span class="craftingButton">Craft Wooden Pickaxe</span>
    <div id="woodenPickaxePopup"> Cost: 50 Wood</div>          
    </a></div>

Comment: Omg... I really should have used the rubber ducky method on my html... I used it on my CSS and Jscript but didn't think something that small would matter. Thanks a million man! The CSS is messed up on Firefox for some reason but works perfectly on Chrome at least!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing both `float: left;` from .craftingButton and `top: 50;` from #woodenPickaxePopup in your CSS.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RBJ9R/1598/)

Comment: This works very well but, I need my crafting buttons to be float: left; so that my page doesn't center them vertically. Basically, I have 3 divs that use crafting buttons on one page, I need to have them align left. If I can't figure something else out, I will definitely use your method as it works very easily for what it does.

Comment: A fair point. Stuiterbal posted a better solution for what you want to accomplish :-)